# What is the meaning of "hear for blocks" in the following sentences

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "hear for blocks" in the following sentences,

> Hoeny is the name of the alligator.
>
> Well, it had to happen. One day, Justin's mother went into the
>   bathroom. Honey grinned at her in a friendly way. She let out a yell
>   you could **hear for blocks**. Soon after that, Honey had to go to the
>   zoo. (source: Justin's  Alligator by Sandra Widener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you yell so loud that people can hear you for miles, it means that you're yelling so loudly that it can be heard at a distance a few miles long. In your example, instead of miles, they just use blocks as a unit of distance. A block is typically defined as a group of buildings bounded by four streets. So, a yell that can be heard for blocks means a yell that can be heard a few streets away from the point of its origin. All this is figurative language, of course. The idea here is that the yell was so loud that people out on the streets could hear it.